# I want program to accept numbers only

Tags: c++

I want my program to accept numbers only between 1 and 4 as input. And if input is an alphabet or or any other number instead of 1, 2, 3 or 4, then it should show an error and prompt the sir user again to input correct values. This is what i'm doing right now.

```
if (x < 1 || x > 4)
{
    cout << "Invalid input!";
}
else if (x == 1)
{
    // rest of the program
}
```

Comment: You forgot `<< endl` after `"Invalid input!"` (I/O is buffered) and you don't show how you are reading `x` ....

Comment: What is the question? Or you are asking us to do the job for you?

Comment: I just want to know. What to do if i want my program to accept NUMBERS only. I know there is some changes need to be done in If ( HERE )

Comment: What you showed is irrelevant to the question.  How has the value of x been acquired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this

```
unsigned char x;
int num=0;

input:
    num =0;
    cout<<"Enter input value"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    num = x - 48;
    if(num>4||num<1)
    {
        //enter again
        goto input;
    }
```

Comment: @NewTo'C' please learn how this works especially if you are going to turn this in as a homework assignment. Hint: What does is the significance of the 48?

Comment: Woah, recommending a solution with "goto" somewhat seems evil to me. This is not a nice style. ;)

Comment: I believe this answer is intentionally designed to give a user a bad score as a homework problem but still work as a solution to the problem.. For that reason I gave kunal a +1.